# Replacing Nan values and blank cells with "0" in excel. my code also replaced text with "0"

Tags: python, pandas

This is subset of a data frame:

```
id        sentence                  ADR      WD
1         really bad symptoms        1        
2         did not help               NAN      1
```

I need to replace `"nan" values and "blank cells" with "0"` The output should be like the following.

```
 id        sentence                  ADR      WD
 1         really bad symptoms        1       0
 2         did not help               0       1
```

This is my code:

```
df_M = df_M.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True).fillna(0)
```

But the problem is that the code also replaced sentences with "0". This is the output of the code:

```
id        sentence                  ADR      WD
 1         0                          1       0
 2         0                          0       1
```

How I can fix it ?

Comment: What's actually in the blank cell? Spaces?

Comment: Change your regex to `r'^\s+$'` if you'd like to preserve the sentences. This won't replace partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

in two steps, assuming "blank" = '':

```
foo = pd.DataFrame([['asdf',1,''],['fdsa',np.nan,1]])
foo.replace(np.nan,0)
foo.replace('',0)
```

Or in one step if you want to be fancy

```
foo.fillna(0).replace('',0)
```

Comment: Thank. There is a problem with this solution. It cannot recognize some of the blank cells. That's why I thought it would be better to use "r'\s+' " to find blank cells. However it created knew problem. Do you know the why your code is not able to recognize some of the blank cells in excel to replace them with 0 ?